# How to destroy rules in a Terraform managed default security group?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When Terraform adopts ownership of the default security group in a VPC, it will delete all current rules and add any that are specified in the `default_security_group` resource. However, when you "destroy" the resource, it does not delete the rules it added to the default security group. I understand that it won't delete the default security group, but I expected it to delete the rules that it added. Is there a straightforward way to delete those rules?

My current workaround is to have a separate module that contains an empty `default_security_group` resource. I build that right before running destroy and that build removes the rules. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "adopts the ownership"? Do you import the default security group into your state file?

If yes, maybe you should handle the default security group with a [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html) instead of a resource:

```
data "aws_security_group" "default" {
  name = "default"
}
```

You can get the ID of the default security group by using `"${data.aws_security_group.default.vpc_id}"`. Now just add the rules, which could be destroyed without touching the security group itself.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Check out the docs on the `aws_default_security_group`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_security_group.html. The relevant sentence is "The aws_default_security_group behaves differently from normal resources, in that Terraform does not create this resource, but instead "adopts" it into management." Additionally, you cannot use external `aws_security_group_rule` resources with the `aws_default_security_group`, which would prevent the solution you describe from working correctly (assuming I understand what you meant by "just add the rules").

Comment: Didn't know that resource by now...
It seems to be expected behavior, that it does not remove the rules (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_security_group.html#removing-aws_default_security_group-from-your-configuration)

When using the data source (see my answer) you should be able to create AND delete rules within your terraform configuration

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this isn't an answer to my question since it involves not using the `aws_default_security_group` resource itself. But it does seem like a good answer to the related question "How to add and remove rules to the default security group without using the `aws_default_security_group`" which I think would be useful to others.

Comment: If you really have to use the `aws_default_security_group`, you could add a `provisioner` with `local-exec` and do some "magic" using the AWS CLI/API to fetch the inline rules and delete them, when the resource is destroyed.

Comment: Yep, that's a good workaround, too. I actually settled on a workaround using a conditional variable and an empty `aws_default_security_group`. Before destroying, I target that resource and set the conditional var such that the empty resource is built. This removes the rules. That way I'm staying within Terraform (I was trying to avoid using CLI or Boto or similar) and it avoids the need for a separate module.

Comment: But why do you prefer to have these kind of workarounds, if there is a simpler way of handling rules within the default security group? I'm just curious, if there is a use case, I might encounter in the future.

Comment: I don't prefer them. I think using a data source is probably the best way to manage rules in the default security group (I use that method for many other security groups). The point of the question was to try and understand how to best use the `aws_default_security_group` resource. Not being able to delete the rules seemed like such an obvious requirement that I thought I must be missing something. Based on our conversation and the lack of other answers, I guess not. The resource is simply not very useful.

Comment: Ok, than we are at the same page :)

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't currently state this, but you can import a default security group using:

```sh
terraform import aws_default_security_group.california sg-<id>
```

I discovered this when moving resources from one solution to another, and forgetting to use `terraform state rm` to remove the resource from the initial codebase :)

You should then be able to edit the resource as usual.